# Getting 401 Error in Laravel Sanctum/Airlock

Tags: laravel, api, next.js, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel as the backend for my **Next JS** app, and **Sanctum** to handle authentication.
I'm able to get the session authentication working just fine on the front end, but when I try to make requests to the *API* from the Node server for **SSR**, I get a `401 Unauthorized error`.

> Is there any way I can have both the client and Node server authenticating?

I'm running the API on `localhost:8000` and the Next server on `localhost:3000`. I overloaded my `env.` with stateful domains in an attempt to get it to work:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000,localhost,localhost:8000,https://localhost:8000,https://localhost,http://localhost,http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: can you provide .env configuration for Sanctum?

Comment: @ShahadatHossain Edited

Answer (score 1):

Try to add Referer header to fetch request

For example:

```
fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    Referer: 'localhost'
  })
```